# Load multiple columns of same type as a List<type> field by means of column name pattern in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, orm

Is there any trick to accomplish this need in Spring-Boot/JPA/Hibernate combo?

I'd like something like to load something like this:

```
| text1 | text2 | text3
------------------------
|  A    |   B   |   C
```

To the following:

```
@Column(name = "text*")
List<String> texts; //Containing {"A","B","C"}
```

If I need to code deep level JPA customizer I might do it as well, as long as it is mantainable

**Edit:** I cannot touch the db

Comment: Why not using one column which hold the three attributes of type array?

Comment: I cannot modify the underlying database schema

Comment: Is there a reason you want such a discrepancy between your schema and your entity? You could easily write a `getTexts()` method that returns the values in a list, but keeps the entity identical to the schema.

Comment: The text* fields might be dynamical sized, or at least, I would prefer supporting it if they change even if it is from time to time

Comment: @Whimusical if they change the db schema, they should change the entity as well. RDBMS are less suitable for dynamic data, and you shouldn't try to force it unless for a good reason. If you're trying to defensively program the application code to work when `text4` and `text5` are added, the main problem is the wrongly normalized schema. You can't **fix** it in code, so you should consider how much work you want to do for a *workaround*. My proposal above is a very lightweight workaround, which can be easily removed if the schema ever gets fixed.